# Why do SGI stl source code use #if 0?

Tags: c++, stl

In the `iterator.h` file of the SGI source code file, line 67:

```
#if 0
using __STD::iterator;
#endif
```

Why do the standard template library coders write this way? Isn't it a better to declare another macro, and use it as a test condition like:

```
#define STD_ITERATOR
#ifndef STD_ITERATOR
using __STD::iterator;
#endif
```

Why write it hard-coded with a *rude* `#if 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#if 0` is typically used when you want to remove something, but you aren't quite sure if you REALLY want to remove it, so you leave it within `#if 0`, so you can take it back again.

Adding extra `#define XX` and using `#ifndef` leads to "namepolution", which gets a bit annoying when you need to use `STD_ITERATOR` as a macro or name in your own code for some reason, only to discover it's defined to nothing in a header that you happen to use, for no good reason at all.

(It is not considered really good style to leave `#if 0` in "release" code - it should be a temporary measure, and should be removed once you are "certain" that it's not needed).

Another very good use of #if 0 is for troubleshooting - e.g. you know your code crashes in function X, but not quite where, and function X is quite large. So put a #if 0 around one half of the function, and if it doesn't crash, you know it's in the if'd out bit. [Obviously with some care so that the code doesn't break simply because you've now taken out some critical parts!]